# Cant send a link to text message using twilio API

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, twilio

I am using a trial version of twilio. I want to send link through text message so user can click that link and any page of application.My application is in MVC(Basically using c# language).

for that I am doing the code as below.

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("Register", "Account",new { Email=username,UserId=user.Id } , protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);
            var message1 = twilio.SendMessage(
                "[MY-TWILIO-NUMBER]", // From (Replace with your Twilio number)
                "[TO-NUMBER]", "Please link on the below link to login to my application: "+ callbackurl);
```

===========================================================================
this code send message to given cell number. But link displaying simply text format. Means we cant click on that link.

e.g.
Sent from your twilio trail account- Please link on the below link to login to my application: http://localhost:50400/Acount/Register?UseeerId=44d24f16-6345736-231vjh347.

Link this displaying in text message we cant click on it. Hos is it possible to show the link inside body parameter of SendMessage method.

Thanks,
Manasi

Comment: What is the device you are seeing this behaviour on?

Comment: @philnash both on android and ios phone..same thing is happened

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the link in the SMS. Sorry, just trying to gather all the info that I can!